# How do I increment the weight of a completion suggest field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am making a completion suggester. I would like to increment the weight of some of the indexed docs by incrementing them. I have:

```
POST /tester/
{
        "mappings": {
          "song": {
            "properties": {
              "suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "simple",
                "search_analyzer" : "simple",
                "payloads": true,
                "preserve_separators": true,
                "preserve_position_increments": true,
                "max_input_length": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
```

// Index a doc

```
PUT tester/song/1
{
    "name" : "Nevermind",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
        "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
        "payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },
        "weight" : 1
    }
}
```

// Increment the weight

```
POST /tester/song/1
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.suggest.weight += 1"
    }
}
```

// The result of GET /tester

```
{
        "_index": "tester",
        "_type": "song",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "ctx._source.suggest.weight += 1"
          }
        }
      }
```

Rather than incrementing the weight it rewrites the document. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First by adding these lines to your configuration you should [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting):

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

Then you need to use `_update` endpoint to update:

```
POST 'localhost:9200/tester/song/1/_update' -d '
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.suggest.weight += 1"
    }
}'
```

Check:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates